# Как обновить некоторые props у компонента ребенка?

Tags: reactjs

Есть компонент ContentMap. У него VotingInfoBlock и GoogleLegend. При клике срабатывает событие  onClickDistrict. И нужно обновить компонент VotingInfoBlock не трогая GoogleLegend. 
Как это правильно сделать?

```
class ContentMap extends Component {

    // ! вот тут я кликнул на районе Москвы и мне надо обновить тексты в блоке
  onClickDistrict(name) {
    this.VotingInfoBlockEl.props.headerTitle= 'Киевский район';
    this.VotingInfoBlockEl.props.headerText= 'Кандидат победивший на выборах это: Бобров 77%';
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div className="mayor2018__map">
        <VotingInfoBlock
          ref={el => {
            this.VotingInfoBlockEl = el;
          }}

          headerTitle="Кунцево"
          headerText="Кандидат победивший на выборах это: "
        />
        <GoogleLegend onClickDistrict={this.onClickDistrict.bind(this)}  />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все обновления в реакте по-нормальному делаются через рендер. Чтобы обновить VotingInfoBlock - нужно просто передать ему нужные свойства в методе render. А для того чтобы можно было каждый раз отображать что-то новое - нужно эти свойства хранить в состоянии (state):

```
class ContentMap extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          headerTitle: 'Кунцево',
          headerText: 'Кандидат победивший на выборах это: ',
      };
  }

  onClickDistrict(name) {
      this.setState({
           headerTitle: 'Киевский район',
           headerText: 'Кандидат победивший на выборах это: Бобров 77%'
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="mayor2018__map">
        <VotingInfoBlock
          headerTitle={this.state.headerTitle}
          headerText={this.state.headerText}
        />
        <GoogleLegend ... />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Теперь вторая проблема - как при этом не обновлять GoogleLegend. Для того чтобы не обновлять GoogleLegend, нужно две вещи:

1. Компонент GoogleLegend должен быть чистым (чистыми являются функциональные компоненты или наследники PureComponent) либо реализовывать адекватный shouldComponentUpdate.
2. Ему нужно передавать каждый раз одну и ту же функцию в свойстве onClickDistrict.

Для того чтобы выполнить пункт 2 - операцию bind придется вынести в конструктор:

```
class ContentMap extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { ... };
      this.onClickDistrict = this.onClickDistrict.bind(this);
  }

  onClickDistrict(name) { ... }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="mayor2018__map">
        <VotingInfoBlock ... />
        <GoogleLegend onClickDistrict={this.onClickDistrict} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: А если есть элемент внук который выводит google карту. И нужно не обновляя всю google карту вывести на ней маркер. То есть вызвать метод внука, но не спровоцировать там render. То как лучше поступать?
Передать его через ref наверх?

Comment: @manking использовать библиотеки для управления общим состоянием (react-redux или react-mobx). Или колхозить на [контекстах](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). Ну или просто писать карту так чтобы ее рендер не был чем-то страшным.

Answer (score 0):

Сила реакта в работе с состоянием. Так воспользуйтесь им

```
class ContentMap extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          headerTitle: 'Кунцево',
          headerText: 'Кандидат победивший на выборах это: ',
      };
  }

    // ! вот тут я кликнул на районе Москвы и мне надо обновить тексты в блоке
  onClickDistrict(name) {
      this.setState({
           headerTitle: 'Киевский район',
           headerText: 'Кандидат победивший на выборах это: Бобров 77%'
      });
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div className="mayor2018__map">
        <VotingInfoBlock
          ref={el => {
            this.VotingInfoBlockEl = el;
          }}

          headerTitle={this.state.headerTitle}
          headerText={this.state.headerText}
        />
        <GoogleLegend onClickDistrict={this.onClickDistrict.bind(this)}  />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: *"И нужно обновить компонент VotingInfoBlock **не трогая GoogleLegend**."*

Comment: а кто его трогает? props у него не меняется, он и не будет перерисовываться

Comment: вообще-то props у него именно что меняются: bind же каждый раз возвращает новое значение

Comment: а, ну да. не учел